# Why aren't most of the displacement noise options available in the node editor?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

For displacement, you have many options, such as marble, clouds, etc., but the node editor only has musgrave, voronoi, and noise. Why is this? Is there a way to obtain these noise options in the node editor? Any answers are appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textures you find in the node editor are render engine based shader nodes, what you see is dependent on currently active render engine, and only available at render time for Cycles and EEVEE, or Material Preview in the viewpo*rt using EEVEE*.

On the other hand, textures available for *Displacement* (or any other modifiers for that matter, like particles, hair, painting among others) must be available at all times, even before rendering, and regardless of the currently active render engine, such as third party ones.

For the purpose of this answer I'll assume you are using Cycles as active render engine, and by the "*node editor textures*" you mean Cycles Shader nodes.

As such the textures you find in the node editor are Cycles Shader textures, capable of GPU computing and other Cycles exclusive features. They only really work if Cycles or EEVEE are used as render engine, and are generally computed at render time, making them unavailable for use in modifiers.

For modifiers, legacy Blender Internal Render Engine based textures are used instead since these have been around far before the emergence of Cycles. They supporting a different set of features and aren't bound by the same constraints required by Cycles. These are computed in different ways, on CPU only, and rely on Blender Internal, and as such are available at all times even if Cycles isn't being used.

You can't really use Cycles shader nodes for modifiers, and the opposite is also true for now, you can't use Blender Internal textures for Cycles shader trees.

For future Blender versions 3.3+ there are plans to eventually comply retire the old Blender Render based textures and replace them by a modern Cycles compatible node system.

Some of them are already available in geometry nodes in an incomplete form, but it will probably require that more systems (like physics simulations and rigging) are modernized into a node based pipeline.

If you really need to use one texture of either system in another one, the only currently known way is to bake it into an image texture, as an intermediate step.