# How to apply custom textures

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender and was just messing around with the texture tab. I've created a very simple texture and can't seem to figure out how to apply it.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the actual texture]

Everywhere tutorial I find always talks about adding an image as a texture. That's not what I'm looking to do. I simply want to apply this texture to the basic cube that Blender opens with. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117950/why-arent-most-of-the-displacement-noise-options-available-in-the-node-editor/117970#117970

Answer (score 3):

Your texture you have here is a brush texture. You need to add a new material to the cube and the add the same texture to the material node tree, possibly recreating the settings you have here as a brush.