# Creating and adding a texture to a material (blender 2.8)

Tags: texturing

I'm fairly new to blender 2.8 and I was wondering how to add a texture that I've created to a material.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117950/why-arent-most-of-the-displacement-noise-options-available-in-the-node-editor/117970#117970 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles/8698#8698

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a texture to any material, simply go in to your shading window. 
--> choose add (shift+A)--> image texture --> plug that in to a principled BSDF tats connected to the material output. 
After that you can simply open up the texture you want and enyoy yore new texture.

P.S look upp some youtub tutorials on the topic