How can i use texture tab textures in my material node

How can i use texture tab textures in my material node
i want my material color to exact Displace modifier Marble shape

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117950/why-arent-most-of-the-displacement-noise-options-available-in-the-node-editor/117970#117970
